# dj-rest-auth registration fetch

Tags: javascript, django, fetch, dj-rest-auth

Using dj-rest-auth for user auth and registration on my react app.
Got login and logout to work using api endpoints in the docs.
Failing to register a user, getting HTTP bad request 400. Reading on the web, explains that there's something wrong with my request but cannot figure what.

EDIT: Tried insomina to simulate POST registration response and got error on a Django's side:

```
ConnectionRefusedError at /api/dj-rest-auth/registration/
[Errno 61] Connection refused
```

register.js

```
fetch('/api/dj-rest-auth/registration/', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        user: 'alalala',
        password1: '1234',
        password2: '1234',
        email: 'ala@gmail.com',
      })
    })
.then(res => {
        res.json()
      })
```

settings.py

```
SITE_ID = 1
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ]
}
REST_AUTH_REGISTER_SERIALIZERS = {
    'REGISTER_SERIALIZER': 'api.serializers.CustomRegisterSerializer'
}
INSTALLED_APPS = [
#local
    'api',
    # 3'rd party apps
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'dj_rest_auth', 

    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'dj_rest_auth.registration',

    # added django but it disable admin login logout pages
    'django.contrib.sites',
    
    # django default...
]
```

Comment: Pls can you show the error, and also drop the RegisterSerializer code

Comment: also to help debug run the endpoint on a client like Postman or Insomnia that way you know if the problem is from the backend or your frontend, i advice you use Insomnia since its better to debug with

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, insomina turned out more convienient than logging error to the js console:) Added error to the top of the question, this error occurs when registering with dj-rest-auth

Comment: so this is the same error you get when you run it on your client?, also can you share your full url, its possible its not seeing your URL or Port.

Comment: this error occurred when trying js fetch, insomnia and directly on the Django’s server dj-rest interface (the one from DRF). Also, I can login and call all of the rest of rest (hah) api’s so I don't think the error has to do anything with the path but can add a full path later

Comment: Try putting the full url in the fetch instead of the path and see if that solves the problem, also if this request needs the user to be authorised then you will have to pass your valid token in the URL.

Comment: yeah, thanks. As mentioned this is likely issue as it not the solved the issue. I can login using dj-rest and logout, and call api requiring logging. The issue is that even when trying to register direcly on python django rest UI view - it prompts that error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in the settings, in config of drf auth, in this case it would work with:

```
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'none'
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'username'
```